# Why is 「元気となる」considered awkward?

Tags: particle-と

From an [IMABI tutorial on the particle と](https://www.imabi.net/tableofcontents.htm):

> [image]

> [image]

As you can see, "元気となる" is marked with an "△/X", which I'm assuming means it's not proper Japanese? What about this sentence is bad though, according to the description above?

It seems to me that sudden, discrete changes towards 元気 are conceptually possible. For example, suppose someone suddenly wins the lottery, and their life *immediately* improves, almost in an instance. Why wouldn't "元気となる" make sense here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, na-adjective+となる should be rare.

- ×静かとなる
- △/×冷静となる

[This](https://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18427) explains the difference as '「～となる」は物事の自然な変化を表すことができません。な形容詞や時間には接続しにくいです', with the following examples.

- ×２時となった。
- ×辺りは静かとなった。
- ×病気となった。

One element would be if somebody can **decide** the state is true. To me, 必要になる is normal but 必要となる works as well (a bit stiff). This is possibly because whether or not a thing is necessary is a discrete state decidable by someone.

Comment: Do you know why is と considered appropriate in 「いよいよ運動会の日となりました」? Isn't the process of time changing from day to another non-discrete? And in 「みぞれが雪となりました」, does the と make sense because we're trying to say the sleet *suddenly* turned into snow?

Comment: @George For the former, I think it is more about the property (of being the time for the event). Also, the date is actually fine with となる. E.g., 12月31日となりました although some sort of 'worth-mentioning'-ness is expected. For the latter, it is noun+だ, so not na-adjective.